# How to include QwebEngineView without getting an error

Tags: c++, qt5, qwebengineview

Question is simple; I get an error "Unknown module `QWebEngineView`" when I write the line `Qt += QWebEngineView` in .pro file.

How to get rid of this ?
I have tried many solutions but still got the error when compiling. If you got a solution please explain it entirely step by step.
I run Qt 5.10.1 with Ming32 5.30.

Comment: QtWebEngine is not available in mingw

Comment: Its the only compilator that works for me or is detected. If you have a solution i'm taking it.

Comment: install visual studio and that does support QtWebEngine, but unfortunately you can not use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use [msys2](http://www.msys2.org/) project that contains mingw64 with patches for qt5.

Write in your .pro file

```
QT += webenginewidgets
```

Add

```
 #include <QWebEngineView>
```

in file that will use QWebEngineView class

Comment: Even if you include what you indicate is not going to solve the problem, the error is caused because QtWebEngine is not available in mingw

Comment: he could use msys2 with mingw64. it has patches to enable build qtwebengine.

Comment: That you must indicate in your answer. :)

Comment: I installed msys2 with mingw64 for qt and it work. But how do I include webengine now ? It says "unknown module"

Comment: There are 3 modules to work with webengine in qt. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-modules.html